# Printing to file python script running as a background process

Tags: python, io, background, centos

I have a python script that takes about 3 hours to run. I want to print some of the data it generates to a .csv file.

I'm on centos and I'm running my script like so:

```
python my_script.py > output.csv &
```

I also tried:

```
python my_script.py &> output.csv
```

Nothing prints to output.csv, not even some test statements right at the beginning of the script.

The next thing I tried was opening a file in my script - `f = open('output.csv', 'a')` and writing to it using `f.write()`. Again, nothing shows up in the file (although it does get created).

How can I create my output.csv with the data that I want? It seems to work normally when it's not a background process but I'd like it to run in the background.

I'm printing just like so:

```
print('hello, this is a test')
```

and in another version, I have something like this:

```
f = open('output.csv', 'a')
f.write('hello, this is a test')
```

I get exactly the same result in both cases. The file gets created, but nothing is actually written to it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We need to understand how you are printing to be of any help. Can you reproduce the problem in small script and post it here

Comment: @Krishna, sure, I will edit the above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try flushing the stdout buffer:

Python >= 3.3:

```
print('hello, this is a test', flush=True)
```

Earlier versions:

```
import sys

print('hello, this is a test')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: i got troubled why my python programme not printing out, oh yes, the "flush" magic